# get a specific char from array of strings with C

Tags: arrays, c, char, printf, c-strings

I have an array of strings I want to print a specific char from:

```
char *Code[17]={"MAIN: add r3, LIST",
                "LOOP: prn #48",
                "lea STR, r6",
                "inc r6",
                "mov r3, K",
                "sub r1, r4",
                "bne END",
                "cmp val1, #-6",
                "bne %END",
                "dec K",
                "jmp %LOOP",
                "END: stop",
                "STR: .string “abcd”",
                "LIST: .data 6, -9",
                ".data -100",
                ".entry K",
                "K: .data 31"};
printf("%s",&Code[1][4]);
```

The char I want to print is "**:**" from the second string (LOOP: prn #48).

When I try to print using **printf("%s",&Code[1][4]);** what I get is "**: prn #48**"

I want to print the char "**:**" alone so I also tried doing printing with %c and got this warning:

> warning: format '%c' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 2 has type 'char *'

How do I get the specific char from a specific string in the array?

Also why do I get A warning that %c expects type int? isn't %c used for printing and scanning A char?

Comment: you need to learn about arrays and pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf("%s",&Code[1][4]);` prints the C string starting at `&Code[1][4]`.

`printf("%c",Code[1][4]);` prints the character `Code[1][4]` (from address `&Code[1][4]`, but that is not relevant as for `%c` the character needs to be passed, not its address).

Answer (score 0):

You try to print a pointer value not the character.

```
printf("%s",&Code[1][4]); // print a string starting at ':'
printf("%c",&Code[1][4]); // try to print address of char
printf("%c",Code[1][4]); // Print the char you want
```

Answer (score 0):

The conversion specifier `c` used to output characters expects a scalar argument of the type `int` (after the integer promotions of the argument expression of the the type `char` to the type `int`) that is converted by the function to the type `unsigned char` and outputted.

However this expression

```
&Code[1][4]
```

has the type `char *` instead of `char`.

On the other hand, the conversion specifier `s` is used to output strings instead of single characters (though using this specifier you can output a single character as it will be shown below).

So what you need is the following

```
printf( "%c", Code[1][4] );
```

You could use the conversion specifier `s` and your argument of the `printf` call provided that you will specify the precision. For example

```
printf( "%.*s", 1, &Code[1][4] );
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *Code[17] = 
    { 
        "MAIN: add r3, LIST",
        "LOOP: prn #48",
        /* other initializers */
    };
    
    printf( "%.*s\n", 1, &Code[1][4] );
    printf( "%c\n", Code[1][4] );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
:
:
```